# When I run myTest.js in Chrome an error appears, what's wrong with my dalek.js file?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, dalekjs

This is the error message that I have every time I run myTest.js. This happens after I installed the my IE driver in my VirtualBox so that I can test from IE browsers.

```
cor03rock at Rockys-MacBook-Pro in ~/Desktop/Jalekoo on dev*
  dalek myTest.js -b chrome

/Users/cor03rock/Desktop/Jalekoo/node_modules/dalekjs/lib/dalek.js:333
    this.driverEmitter.emit('killAll');
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
    at Object.Dalek._shutdown (/Users/cor03rock/Desktop/Jalekoo/node_modules/dalekjs/lib/dalek.js:333:24)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at process._fatalException (node.js:272:26)
```

Jalekoo is my Dalek folder.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you could post a reduced test case & what DalekJS, NodeJS version your on, as well as your operating system. Maybe your projects directory layout could also help spotting the error.

You are also talking about having installed the IE driver & your example call shows `-b chrome`. So do you might have mistaken that.

Also, does that error occur with other browsers (PhantomJS for example) or only for IE (Chrome?).

Would love to help you out, but I need some more information to be able to.